# What are such "off-by-a-factor" ring maps called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology

Suppose $R,S$ are (*non*-unital) rings. What is the term for a function $f:R\rightarrow S$ such that

- $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ for all $a,b\in R$, and
- there is some $u\in S$ such that for all $a,b\in R$ we have $uf(ab)=f(a)f(b)$?

I'm currently calling these "weak homomorphisms" (and "weak embeddings" in the injective case), but I suspect they have an actual name.

For example, let $R=\mathbb{Q}$ and let $S$ be the ring of polynomials with rational coefficients whose constant terms are integers. The map $R\rightarrow S:q\mapsto qx$  is of course not a homomorphism, and indeed there is no homomorphism from $R$ to $S$, but it does satisfy the weaker property above via $u=x$.

(I'm primarily running into this notion in the context of [certain models of Robinson arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717258/generic-behavior-amongst-polynomialish-models-of-mathsfq), the idea being that "sufficiently generic" such models admit weak embeddings from lots of rings and this leads to some interesting structural properties, but I'm also interested in them in other contexts - including non-unital ones.)

Comment: Note that $u=f(1)$ which is more explicit. Also this notion turns up in the context of [multiplicative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function). It would be nice to have a name for the "off-by-a-factor" version.

Comment: @Somos Oops, that was a typo - (very belatedly) fixed!

Comment: In recent years the notion of *approximate groups* has been developed. This seems to be somewhat an analogue/generalisation.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I read the Wikipedia article on approximate groups. I don't see the connection because they are not defined in terms of functional equations.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - are these functions $f$ assumed to be maps of abelian groups?

Comment: Your question is not clear on one critical point about quantifiers. You state that there is some $\,u\in S\,$ but how does it depend on the values of $\,a\,$ or $\,b\,$ or does it hold for **all** values?

Comment: @Somos Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @hm2020 Clarified, thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber - It would be interesting if you could explain the motivation for the study of these generalized maps of rings - please include such a motivation.

Comment: @hm2020 The motivation is basically given in the last paragraph - such maps arise naturally when trying to give shape to the idea that a ring $R$ appearing in a sequence $\mathcal{R}$ gives some "coarse structure" to the (semi)ring $\mathsf{Rob}_\mathcal{R}$ (using the notation of the [MO version](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405692/generic-behavior-of-polynomialish-models-of-mathsfq) of that question).

Comment: This reminds me of the notion of Crossed homomorphism https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Crossed_homomorphism

Comment: From additivity we get $f(na)=nf(a)$ and so $uf(na)=f(n)f(a)=unf(a)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}, a\in R.$ Given that not all images are zero divisors, we get $f(n)=un.$ This looks close to simple left multiplication by $u.$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I know of a term, but I'm going to show two situations where these objects behave very differently. The first, which seems closest to the kind of situation you want, makes this object 'essentially a homomorphism'. The second means that it is no restriction at all. It all depends on the choice of $u$.

I'm going to assume that $R$ and $S$ are commutative, although it is just so I don't need to keep track of sidedness. Let $R^2$ denote the set of products $r_1r_2$, for $r_i\in R$. If $X\subset R$, let $\overline{f(X)}$ denote the subring generated by $f(X)$. (Note that $\overline{f(R)}$ need not be equal to $f(R)$...) We may assume that $S=\overline{f(R)}$ without loss of generality.

The first situation is where $u$ is not a zero divisor in $S$, in particular where $S$ is an integral domain. In the localized ring $S'=S[u^{-1}]$, $u$ is a unit. Let $f':R\to S'$ be given by $f'(r)=u^{-1}f(r)$. Then $f'$ is a ring homomorphism.

To see this, notice that $$f'(r_1+r_2)=u^{-1}(f(r_1)+f(r_2))=u^{-1}f(r_1)+u^{-1}f(r_2))=f'(r_1)+f'(r_2).$$
Secondly,
$$ f'(r_1)f'(r_2)=u^{-2}f(r_1)f(r_2)=u^{-1}f(r_1r_2)=f'(r_1r_2).$$
(Commutativity is needed here, or at least that $u$ is central.)

The opposite position is when $u=0$. Then, for any abelian group $S$ and homomorphism from $(R,+)$ to $S$, it extends to a map $R\to S'$ where $S'$ is the ring with set $S$ and multiplication $0$.

These are two very different contexts, and hopefully the first is what you want, and this is enough to answer your question!