# Term for "field-like" algebraic object with infinitely-many "scaled" multiplication" operations parameterized by its elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, universal-algebra

The motivation is an object which generalizes the notion of percentages.

Consider the the set $\mathbb{R}$ along with the usual binary addition operation $+$ and infinitely-many binary multiplication operations $\boldsymbol{\cdot}_\alpha$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a\boldsymbol{\cdot}_\alpha b = (\alpha a) \cdot b$.

For instance, $50\boldsymbol{\cdot}_{0.01} 6 = (0.01\cdot50) \cdot b$

You can easily prove that the set $\mathbb{R}$ with $+$ and any fixed $\boldsymbol{\cdot}_\alpha$ is a field. The $\alpha = 1$ case corresponds to the usual definition of field $\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha=0.01$ corresponds to a field with a "percentage of" as it's product operation. If, for some twisted reason, one wanted to work with "per**penta**ges" one would consider the $\alpha = 0.2$ case.

This structure represents arbitrarily scaled multiplication and satisfies the field axioms for any fixed scalar. Working with this structure was motivated by the following question: "How can I most effectively procrastinate studying for the GRE and punish myself for making stupid math mistakes on easy percentage problems?"

Are there references to comparable objects anywhere/what would you call this type of thing?

Comment: A one-dimensional [triple system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_system)?

Comment: Based on the idea that an affine space is a vector space with the origin forgotten, I would suggest the (I think unused) term "affine field." Given a field $F=(A; \oplus, \odot)$, let $F_\alpha=(A;\oplus, \odot_\alpha)$ be defined analogously to $(\mathbb{R};+,\cdot_\alpha)$; then for each $\alpha,\beta\in A$ we have a canonical isomorphism $F_\alpha\cong F_\beta$. Basically, the structure $(A; \oplus, \{\odot_\alpha:\alpha\in A\})$ already determines $F$ up to isomorphism, it just doesn't tell us where the multiplicative unit is.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The multiplicative unit is $\alpha^{-1}$.

Comment: Incidentally, things get a bit more interesting if we look at unital rings instead. In this context we also get a somewhat odd notion of "nice map" between unital rings, namely those which fail to be homomorphisms only due to a "multiplicative shift" - see [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717298/what-are-such-off-by-a-factor-ring-maps-called).